# Get the value of an IntegerChoices field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have the following Django (3.2) code:

```
class AType(models.IntegerChoices):
    ZERO = 0, 'Zero'
    ONE = 1, 'One'
    TWO = 2, 'Two'

class A(models.Model):
    a_type = models.IntegerField(choices=AType.choices)
```

Also, that I have a Django template with a variable `a`:

```
{{a.a_type}} is a number.
```

How do I get "Zero" (the string associated with a_type)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) instance method:

```py
{{ a.get_a_type_display }} is a number
```

Comment: In templates is not necesary to use parenthesis, just use `{{ a.get_a_type_display }}`