# Get the value of an IntegerChoices object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have the following Django (3.2) code:

```
class AType(models.IntegerChoices):
    ZERO = 0, 'Zero'
    ONE = 1, 'One'
    TWO = 2, 'Two'

a = AType.ZERO
```

How do I get "Zero" (the string associated with `a`)?

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667983/get-the-value-of-an-integerchoices-value-in-django), except here we only have the IntegerChoices object, and not an associated model object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.label`:

```
>>> a = AType.ZERO
>>> a.label
'Zero'
```